# Issue with SQL aggregate / lookup value and prevent over-counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables:

**Table X**

```
Product  Type   Sales
1   a   1
1   b   1
1   c   0
1   a   2
```

**Table Y**

```
Product Inventory
1   10
```

I would like my query to return:

```
Product type    sales   inventory
1          a    3       10
1          b    1       0
1          c    0       0
```

Issue is using aggregate functions and not over counting the inventory. Example:

```
select X.product, X.type, sum(X.sales), sum( case when X.sales > 0 then Y.inventory else 0 end) 
from x,y
where x.product = y.product 
group by x.product,x.type
```

Comment: What does this data mean? Are types of product different things?

Comment: A product can have different types (features/options) but is what is kept in inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you are basing the final result on the `sales`, this should give you the result:</strike>

```
select distinct x1.product,
  x1.type,
  x2.totalsales,
  case when x1.sales > 0 then y.inventory else 0 end
from x x1
left join
(
  select product,
      type,
      sum(sales) as TotalSales
  from x
  group by Product, Type
) x2
  on x1.product = x2.product
  and x1.type = x2.type
left join y
  On Y.Product = x1.Product
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aca5c/16)

I am unsure why you have the `inventory` for `b` listed as zero in your sample result considering it has a total sales greater than zero.

**Edit #1**:

Based on your comments, I would suggest looking at using `row_number()`:

```
select product, 
  type,
  totalsales,
  case when rn = 1 then inventory else 0 end inventory
from
(
  select x.product,
    x.type,
    sum(sales) TotalSales,
    row_number() over(partition by x.product order by x.type) rn,
    y.inventory
  from x 
  inner join y
    on x.product = y.product
  group by x.product, x.type, y.inventory
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f86a5/11)

Or if you cannot group by `inventory`, then join outside of the subquery:

```
select src.product, 
  src.type,
  src.totalsales,
  case when rn = 1 then inventory else 0 end inventory
from
(
  select x.product,
    x.type,
    sum(sales) TotalSales,
    row_number() over(partition by x.product order by x.type) rn
  from x 
  group by x.product, x.type
) src
inner join y
  on src.product = y.product
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f86a5/13)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The issue is that the inventory is at the product level (not type) and I want it to show up once in the output, in the first row (or any of the rows for the same product, but only once).

Comment: @DimitriKaspersky what rdbms are you using? mysql, sql server, oracle?

Comment: @DimitriKaspersky Happy to help, if this answer was helpful, be sure to accept it via the checkmark on the left.  It will help future visitors and you get reputation from accepting.